# Insert data, copy result and make result active cell

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently working on a worksheet which works on inputting initial data (say A1:A3) summing this data in A6 (which I haven't included in the code) and then copying the data from A1:A3 to B1:B3, adding `1` to each cell from B1:B3, taking the data from B1:B3 and repeating this procedure until the tenth column. The code below shows what I have tried out. I'm having problems with copying the data from successive columns as when I run the following lines:

```
LR = Cells.Find(What:="*",SearchDirection:=xlPrevious,SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row 
LC = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
Cells(LR, LC).CurrentRegion.Select
```

it selects the summed value as opposed to the data (A1:A3). Code:

```
Sub test()

Dim LR As Long, LC As Long
For X = 1 To 10
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Cells(1, X) = X + 1
Cells(2, X) = X + 1
Cells(3, X) = X + 1
LR = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows).Row
LC = Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns).Column
Cells(LR, LC).CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Copy
Cells(LR - 2, LC + 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
Next X

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for writing this as an answer (maybe i got you wrong) but its to much to write it in a comment...

im confused...

```
Cells(1, X) = X + 1
Cells(2, X) = X + 1
Cells(3, X) = X + 1
```

always sets `A1:A3` to 2... also the formula in A6 always messes up pasting it to B4... what do you want it to do exactlty?

do you look for something like this:

```
Sub test()
  Dim X As Byte
  For X = 2 To 10
    Cells(1, X) = Cells(1, X - 1) + 1
    Cells(2, X) = Cells(2, X - 1) + 1
    Cells(3, X) = Cells(3, X - 1) + 1
    Cells(6, X - 1).Copy
    Cells(6, X).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormulas
  Next X
End Sub
```

or this:

```
Sub test2()
  Dim X As Byte
  For X = 2 To 10
    Cells(1, X) = Cells(1, X - 1) + 1
    Cells(2, X) = Cells(2, X - 1) + 1
    Cells(3, X) = Cells(3, X - 1) + 1
    Cells(4, X) = Cells(6, X - 1).Value
  Next X
End Sub
```

However... each solution just increases the value for row 1 to 3 by 1 for each column -> B1 would be `=A1 + 1` which you could copy and paste it to the range of `B1:J3`
Also as it looks B4 is just `=A6` which also could be copy pasted (to `C4:J4)`

at least, i dont know why you want to use VBA for something like that... maybe i miss something big...